# R Lattice Plot Multiple Lines with Specific Color

Tags: r, lattice

I have two problems that I am having trouble to solve for. Firstly when I do a multiple column matrix plot using lattice `xyplot`, I find that all the points are connected. How can I get separate disconnected lines?

```
x<-cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
xyplot(x~1:nrow(x),type="l")
```

Secondly, I am having trouble figuring out how to make one line thicker than the other. For example, given that I want column 1, then column 1's line will be thicker than that of column 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lattice plotting paradigm,like that of ggplot2 that followed it, expects data to be in long format in dataframes:

```
dfrm <- data.frame( y=c(rnorm(10),rnorm(10)),
                    x=1:10, 
                    grp=rep(c("a","b"),each=10))
xyplot(y~x, group=grp, type="l", data=dfrm, col=c("red","blue"))
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the most elegant solution but it gets the job done:

```
x<-cbind(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))
plot1<-xyplot(x[,1]~1:nrow(x),type="l",col="red",lwd=3)
plot2<-xyplot(x[,2]~1:nrow(x),type="l")

library(latticeExtra)
plot1+plot2
```

I assumed that you wanted V1 and V2 plotted against the number of observations. 
Otherwise you indeed only have one line. 
You can adjust the axis and labels according to taste.